# PHP как правильно работать с JSON?

Tags: php, json, веб-программирование, структуры-данных, типы-данных

Мне нужно прочитать файл, разобрать его на массив, дописать строку и записать снова json. Как правильно это сделать?

Я пробую так, но ничего не выходит:

```
$file = file_get_contents('json.txt', true);
$name = "name";
$email = "email";
if(isset($file)){
$arr = array();
}
$arr[count($arr)+1]["name"] = $name;
$arr[count($arr)]["email"] = $email;
echo json_encode($arr);
$decode = json_decode($file ,true);
$fp = fopen("json.txt", "w");
fwrite($fp, json_encode($arr) );
fclose ($fp);
```

На выходе нужно получить:

```
{"1":{"name":"name","email":"email1"}, "2":{"name":"name","email":"email1"}}
```

Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так попробуйте :)

```
$filename = 'json.txt';
$name = "name";
$email = "email";
$arr = array();

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $file = file_get_contents('json.txt', true);
    $arr = json_decode($file ,true);
} 

$arr[count($arr)+1]["name"] = $name;
$arr[count($arr)]["email"] = $email;
echo json_encode($arr);
$decode = json_decode($file ,true);
$fp = fopen($filename, "w");
fwrite($fp, json_encode($arr));
fclose ($fp);
```

В вашем примере, arr всегда пустой при наличии данных из файла.

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек! )

Comment: Немного исправил код, добавил функцию file_exists, а то у Вас там стоял isset, который всегда по сути будет true возвращать в коде.